# Error with HTML viewport

Tags: html, css

my current HTML with this viewport:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`
is providing undesired results such as these:

[image]

While deleting `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`
provided me with another undesirable result as text gets unreadable, like this:

[image]

## What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can toggle <meta> viewport settings, or there is something wrong with your HTML / CSS which you'll need to isolate further and add the code here.

Comment: do are you trying in a tablet ?

Comment: Without the complete markup showing the problem, there is no way for us to help. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" initial-scale="1">
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to declare correctly all tags:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```